# Get Data in forms fail with Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, post, null

My controller is:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new Links());

$peticion = $this->getRequest();

if ($peticion->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bind($peticion);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $data = $form->getData();  
            }   
        }
```

I have a Entity "Links" and a form class called "links", but in controller, in $data, all the fields of the form is NULL.

---------- Form class

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {      
        $builder
            ->add('licenses', integer, array('label' => 'Number Licenses', 'required' => false))
            ->add('Years', 'choice', array('choices'=> array('y1' => '1 year', '3y' => '3 years'),'label' => 'Years license', 'required' => false))
            ->add('Type', 'choice', array('choices'=> array('TypeA' => 'Type A', 'TypeB' => 'TypeB'),'label' => 'License Type', 'required' => false));
    }

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Me\WebBundle\Entity\Links'
        ));
    }
```

---------- View added

```
<form action="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('generate_links') ?>" method="post" <?php echo $view['form']->enctype($form) ?> >
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Generate Links</legend>
        <?php echo $view['form']->widget($form) ?>
    </fieldset>
    <input class="profile_button" value="Generate link" type="submit" />

</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you show your Form class please.

Comment: yes, just is added in the original post. Thanks

Comment: in setDefaultOptions() you set the `data_class`, right?

Comment: Yes, i have added this function in original post, thanks.

Comment: Which version of Symfony? Also, can you post your html with the form.

Comment: My version is Symfony 2.2.1

Comment: HTML View is added, thanks

Comment: if you `var_dump($_POST);` in your Controller, can you see the form there filled with all values?

Comment: Yes, with var_dump I can see values

Comment: Try adding a new instance of your Links entity to the form creation: `$form = $this->createForm(new Links(), new LinksEntity());` - you might need to `use` Links as LinksEntity` at the top of your Controller.

Comment: Not works, all the values in $data are NULL

Comment: At create form, you are passing the FormType, not the Entity right? So the new Links is not your entity? Would be better if you change the name of your formtype to LinksType, cause maybe you have a "use" for the Entity

Comment: I think you are confused. The first parameter for the createForm method should be a new LinksType(). The second parameter should be the new Links() entity. (I can see in the form declaration that your entity is named Link).

Comment: Agree with András: To avoid confusion name your forms "SomenthingType" i.e. LinksType.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your form class is LinksType and your entity is Links:

```
$entity = new Links();
$form = $this->createForm(new LinksType(), $entity);

$peticion = $this->getRequest();

if ($peticion->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bind($peticion);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                //At this point $entity is populated with data.
                //You wouldn't need form->getData() to access data:
                //Next two lines would have the same output:
                $this->get('logger')->debug($entity->getLicences());
                $this->get('logger')->debug($form->get('licences')->getData());
                $data = $form->getData();
    }   
}
```

Comment: You would want to use getData() only for non-mapped form fields ('mapped'=>false)